# Reading a custom encoded network stream from a MediaElement control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I'm developing a **Windows 8 Windows Store app (XAML/C#)** in which I have a ***MediaElement*** control. The *MediaElement* control takes as a source either a *Uri* or a *IRandomAccessStream*.

In my case I have as input **a URI pointing to a custom encoded resource** (and the stream is endless, so I need to be able to read it whilst it's downloading).

What I'd like to do is set the source of my *MediaPlayer* to my url, let the player handle the download, yet be called whenever it needs to read something so I can decode it on the fly.

In Silverlight, a *[MediaStreamSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediastreamsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)* would seem to be the way to go but it does not exist in WinRT ([a light implementation sample does exist though](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/MediaStreamSource-media-dfd55dff)).

What would be the best way to set that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:
I started from Microsoft's "[MediaStreamSource media extension sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/MediaStreamSource-media-dfd55dff)" and then implemented my own *MediaStreamSource* class in C#.
Yet, using a custom media stream source, I could not reuse the existing download mechanism so I created my own based on WinRT's HttpClient class which worked great.

Final recipe is:

- Implement your custom media stream source so the MediaElement can read your file,
- Use the HttpClient class to issue HTTP requests to download my stream chunk by chunk and pass it through my media source to my media element.

Answer (score 0):

The [Media extensions sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096) should be what you are looking for. It explains how to provide your own decoder.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for. Problem is Media Extensions should be in C++, so the MediaStreamSource sample suits better (extension in C++ but the actual decoding logic is implemented in C#).